# Are these shia allegations true about Hazrat Umar (RZ) Marriage?

Tags: nikah, shia-sunni, sahaba

"Umar asks Imam Ali (AS) for his daughter in marriage, and Imam Ali (AS) asks him to leave and then Imam Ali asks his daughter to go to Umar, and when she arrives Umar asks her to marry him, and places his hand on her leg and uncovers her leg!!!!!!  She immediately says to him you do this to me!  If you were not the ruler I would have broken your nose. And she leaves the room. She tells Imam Ali of what happened and added 'You sent me to a vile old man.'  But Ali nevertheless marries her to him!"  al-Estee'aab  4/1954

Umar asks Imam Ali (AS) for his daughter in marriage, and Imam Ali (AS) asks him to leave and then Imam Ali asks his daughter to make herself beautiful to go to Umar!!!  And when Umar saw her he placed his hand on her leg and asked her to marry him . . . when she came back to her father Imam Ali asked her what did Umar tell you, she replied Umar kissed me and placed his hand on my leg and asked me to marry him.  Then Ali married her to him!!!!!"  Taareekh Baghdaad 6/182

Ibn Hajar reports in his book al-Esaabah that "Umar asks Imam Ali (AS) for his daughter Umm Kolthum (AS) in marriage, and Imam Ali (AS) asks him to leave and then Imam Ali asks his daughter to go to Umar, and when she arrives Umar placed his hand on her leg and uncovers her leg!!!!!!  The daughter of Imam Ali (AS) says to him if you were not the ruler I would have gouged your eyes . . . ." al-Esaabah 4/321

These reports are about Hazrat Umar (RZ) marriage with Hazrat Ali (RZ) Daughter. Are these reports true?

Comment: Are you looking for shia perspective or sunni perspective. As sunnis I don't think we believe in those books you referenced to. Those are most likely shia books.

Answer (score 0):

There are many differences between scholars regarding the principle of marriage of the daughter of Ali (as) with Umar. Some Shiite scholars completely reject it and others who accept it believe that Imam Ali accepted it by force. Some Shiite scholars, such as Sheikh Mofid, have denied the marriage, and Agha Bozorg Tehrani cites several books written against the marriage.
Ibn Shahr Ashob says from the words of Abu Muhammad Nobakhti: The marriage took place but Umm Kulthum was small. He waited to grow up, but Umar died before the wedding

But there are still differences about the narration that you are narrating and it has been quoted only in some Sunni sources. The family of Ibn Jozi says about this act of Umar: By God, such a thing is ugly even if Umm Kulthum was a slave; Omar had no right to do so because according to the Muslim consensus, it is not permissible to touch a non-mahram woman.
Some Shiite scholars also accept the occurrence of this incident. There are also narrations about this. For example, the sixth Imam of the Shiites, Imam Sadegh (AS), was asked about Umm Kulthum's marriage to Umar, and Imam (AS) said: She is a girl who was usurped from us.

https://www.porseman.com/article/%D8%A7%D8%B2%D8%AF%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%AC-%D8%A7%D9%85-%D9%83%D9%84%D8%AB%D9%88%D9%85-%D8%A8%D8%A7-%D8%B9%D9%85%D8%B1/44803

https://fa.wikishia.net/view/%D8%A7%D9%85%E2%80%8C%DA%A9%D9%84%D8%AB%D9%88%D9%85_%D8%AF%D8%AE%D8%AA%D8%B1_%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%85_%D8%B9%D9%84%DB%8C(%D8%B9)#%D8%A7%D8%B2%D8%AF%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%AC_%D8%A8%D8%A7_%D8%B9%D9%85%D8%B1_%D8%A8%D9%86_%D8%AE%D8%B7%D8%A7%D8%A8

https://fa.wikishia.net/view/%D8%A7%D8%B2%D8%AF%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%AC_%D8%A7%D9%85%E2%80%8C%DA%A9%D9%84%D8%AB%D9%88%D9%85_%D8%A8%D8%A7_%D8%B9%D9%85%D8%B1_%D8%A8%D9%86_%D8%AE%D8%B7%D8%A7%D8%A8#cite_ref-11